# Scraping table with puppeter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have thefollowing script with puppeter that works correctly , this code extract all information about table.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const tableRows = await page.$$('table > tbody tr');

    await page.goto("https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/espana/liga-endesa/partidos/");

    const time = await page.evaluate(() => {

        const tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr .time'));
        return tables.map(table => table.textContent)
     });

    const teamHome = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr .team-home'));
        return tables.map(table => table.textContent)
     });

     const teamAway = await page.evaluate(() => {
        const tables = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table tr .team-away'));
        return tables.map(table => table.textContent)
     });


     for (let i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
        console.log(time[i]);
        console.log(teamHome[i]);
        console.log(teamAway[i]);
     }  

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Now I try to create this in a better way and I have the following code.

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("https://www.mismarcadores.com/baloncesto/espana/liga-endesa/partidos/");
    console.log("started evalating");
    var data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('table tr')
      ).map(row => {
        return {
          time: row.querySelector(".time"),
          teamHome: row.querySelector(".team-home"),
          teamAway: row.querySelector(".team-away")
        };
      });
    });
  console.log(data);
})();
```

When I try to execute the second script I receive and undefined.

The result will be to pass the first script to second script.

Could anyone helps to me ?

Comment: You are missing `return` in front of `Array.from`.

Comment: Thank is working now , but now I couldn't extract the information jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `tr` elements more (like by adding `.stage-scheduled` class) and to return `.textContent` properties instead fo elements themselves. Try this:

```js
    var data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return Array.from(
        document.querySelectorAll('table tr.stage-scheduled')
      ).map(row => {
        return {
          time: row.querySelector(".time").textContent,
          teamHome: row.querySelector(".team-home").textContent,
          teamAway: row.querySelector(".team-away").textContent,
        };
      });
    });
```